# "Contact Show fields" does not show the street address in autocomplete (civicrm_webform)

Tags: webform-civicrm

I am trying to show the street field but it doesn't appear in the selector. The field is selected but it doesn't work, Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think the Display name field offers every single field that is checked in the CiviCRM Tab - i think they are pre constructed. if you need new ones to show then it probably requires a patch and it may be better to discuss at drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Maybe I propose the change in the project.